# scrollable div with header and footer in floating column

Tags: css

I have a (sometimes) very long table with a div after it, containing controls that should always be displayed. When the table outgrows the container, the table needs to scroll, leaving the controls visible wherever you happen to be at in the table. I can't absolute position the controls to the bottom of the div because the table isn't ALWAYS long. When the table is short, the controls should be at the base of the table.

It's worth noting that the parent container is not actually a completely fixed height. It's inside an angularJS template and when the browser window is resized, the height is recalculated and set on the div. Since my angularJS app is adding rows on the fly and there's the potential for resizing, it's far less than desirable to have a javascript solution. I'm hoping for something with html/css and compatible with IE8.

When the table is short:

```
---------- container -------------
---- short table ----
row...
row...
---------------------
controls
---------------------

whitespace

----------------------------------
```

when the table is long:

```
---------- container -------------
-- long table w/scroll --
row...
row...
row...
row...
row...
row...
-------------------------
controls
---------- end container ---------
```

I set up a fiddle to test this out with th this so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/m3qrmzn7/1/

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="leftContent">
            <table>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="rightTableHead">
            barfoo..
        </div>
        <div id="rightScrollable">
            <table>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foobar</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="rightTableFoot">
            barfoo..
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #333;
}
#left {
    margin-right: -100px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #999;
}
#leftContent {
    margin-right: 100px;
}
#right {
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #ccc;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#rightTableHead,
#rightTableFoot {
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 40px;
}
#rightScrollable {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#rightTableFoot {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Count number of rows the table displays and with set value, chose if which way you display it.

```
<?php
    $rows = request->rowCount();
?>
<span id="rows"> <?php echo $rows; ?> </span>
```

JS.:

```
var x = document.getElementById("rows").innerHTML;
if(x < X)
{
    document.getElementById("controls").style.positionFixed = "bottom: 0px;";
}
```

Comment: I wish it were that simple. I'll add a few details to my post that I initially left out. It's inside an angularJS template and the parent container is "fixed" in the sense that when the browser window is resized, the height is recalculated and set on the div. This means there's no magic number of rows to make a decision upon.